# View your own answer to a deleted question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I'd like to be able to view an answer I gave to a question that it seems the person who asked the question has deleted.  How do I get to this?

Comment: Do you remember the title of the question?  Maybe I can look it up and write it here foryou :)

Comment: Nope. Don't remember.  However, I now I have the words Mathematica, Classify, and TopProbabilities (as one word) in the text of my answer.

Comment: @Dawny33 I found the post link as I got a badge from it.  [6766](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6766) However, it still shows as deleted so I can't see it even though I have the link.  I think you should still be able to see your answer to a post in your activity even if the poster deletes the post.

Comment: Added your answer as an answer here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your answer to the deleted question

Question: Machine learning algorithm to predict product service requests

Mathematica code below as I could not get it to work in R and OP asked to see what was done with Mathematica. More information on any of the functions can be found at the [Wolfram Language & System Documentation Center](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/). If you are wondering all functions/packages there are included standard with Mathematica so no need to purchase additional packages.

Import all rows and columns 1, 2, 7, and 9 from the first sheet of the spreadsheet.

```
data = Import[
   FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "Sample_Set.xlsx"}], 
    {"XLSX", "Data", 1, All, {1, 2, 7, 9}}];
```

Clean items that are missing at least column entry. Also, drop header row.

```
cleanedData = Select[! Or @@ ((# == "") & /@ # ) &]@Rest@data;
```

`(# == "") &` is a nested pure function that is `Map`ed (`/@`) over each entry of each row to create a list of equality test to `""`.  `Or` is `Apply`ed (`@@`) to the list and negated (`!`) to `Select` only those rows that have an entry in all columns. `Rest` drops the first row and keeps the *rest*.

Format into  example->class for Classify function.  The customer request comment is split into words and restricted to words that can be found in the dictionary.
The {action, part} pairs are joined into one field *action+":"+part*.

```
classifyFormatted = (
     {
       Select[Length[DictionaryLookup[#, 1]] > 0 &]@TextWords@ToLowerCase[#[[1]]], #[[2]]
     } -> #[[3]] <> ":" <> #[[4]]) & /@ cleanedData;
```

Map over each row of `cleanedData` to create a rule per row of
`{list of dictionary words from comment, issue} -> action+":"+part`

Drop items for which no dictionary words were found in the customer request.

cleanedClassifyFormatted = Select[classifyFormatted, Length[#[[1, 1]]] != 0 &];

For each row check the length of the first sub-item of the first item (the list of dictionary words) is not zero.

Remove duplicate entries.

```
cleanedClassifyFormatted = DeleteDuplicates[cleanedClassifyFormatted];
```

Now we are left with 427 items from the original 499.

```
Dimensions@cleanedClassifyFormatted
(* 427 *)
```

Use `Classify` to create a `ClassifierFunction`.  I let the selection algorithm choose the best method instead of explicitly selecting one. I also leave the last 27 items to test the classifier by passing in from the 1st to the 28th-last items only.

```
c1 = Classify[cleanedClassifyFormatted[[1 ;; -28]]];
ClassifierInformation[c1]
```

[image]

The output tells us that there are 136 classes from 400 observations based on 2 features.

Test classification on last 27 entries.

```
Transpose@{c1 /@ cleanedClassifyFormatted[[-27 ;;]][[All, 1]], 
   cleanedClassifyFormatted[[-27 ;;]][[All, 2]]} // TableForm
```

[image]

As you can see it does not predict very well.  Looking at the `Tally` of the top ten classes we see that there may not be enough support for all classes.

```
(SortBy[-#[[2]] &]@Tally[cleanedClassifyFormatted[[1 ;; -28, 2]]])[[
  1 ;; 10]] // TableForm
```

[image]

Examining how may items have a particular tally we see that the is not enough support across all classes for a reasonable classification.

```
TableForm[
 Sort@Tally[Tally[cleanedClassifyFormatted[[1 ;; -28, 2]]][[All, 2]]],
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Tally", "Num Items"}}]
```

[image]

Most of the classes have one observation so and only 1 has 41 observations.  The sample does not have enough observations for the pairs.

---

### **Update**

Added just classifying the part used to give get more support for the classes.

Reused `cleanedClassifyFormatted` and just `StringDrop`ed the part before the ":" from the rule of each entry.

```
cCF2 = #[[1]] -> StringDrop[#[[2]], StringPosition[#[[2]], ":", 1][[1, 1]]] & /@ cleanedClassifyFormatted;
```

Then we can execute the same commands as above to classify with this set.

Top ten `Tally`

```
(SortBy[-#[[2]] &]@Tally[cCF2[[1 ;; -28, 2]]])[[1 ;; 10]] // TableForm
```

[image]

Number of items per `Tally`.

```
TableForm[Sort@Tally[Tally[cCF2[[1 ;; -28, 2]]][[All, 2]]],
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Tally", "Num Items"}}]
```

[image]

`ClassifierFunction` construction.

```
c2 = Classify[cCF2[[1 ;; -28]]];
ClassifierInformation[c2]
```

[image]

Here I'll switch it up by showing the top 3 probabilities from the `ClassifierFunction` for 5 of the test data sets and compare to the actual class.

```
Grid[Transpose@{Column@c2[#, {"TopProbabilities", 3}] & /@ 
    cCF2[[-27 ;;]][[1 ;; 5, 1]], cCF2[[-27 ;;]][[1 ;; 5, 2]]}, 
 Background -> {None, {{None, LightBlue}}} ]
```

[image]

The free text with sample size is the biggest limiter for this. I've attempted to create some structure with it by keeping only words that are found in the dictionary but there are still a lot of variations there. If you have them, I would suggest adding more structured fields like type of appliance, age of appliance, brand, and so on.  These better define the classes.

You should also read up on the `Method` options of `Classify` and select the ones best suited for your data.

Comment: Many thanks, Dawny. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I don't think that can be done. However, have a look at this [meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130415/302377).

But, the moderators can see deleted posts.